# Time is not converted correctly - DateTime.newInstance()

Tags: datetime, timezone

I have a DateTime variable dt in trigger.Insert of a record which debug result is :

```
    USER_DEBUG [185]|DEBUG|2016-12-08 00:00:00
```

We can see that it's the start time 12:00 AM of date: Dec 8th 2016.
When i convert dt using DateTime.newInstance

```
    DateTime.newInstance(dt.year(), dt.month(), dt.day(), 0, 0, 0);
```

The result i get is :

```
    USER_DEBUG [187]|DEBUG|2016-12-07 08:00:00
```

My SF org has timezone is

```
    (GMT-08:00) Pacific Standard Time (America/Los_Angeles)
```

After convertion, dt is start time for the day before!! : Dec 7th 2016

Any one can help me, please?

Comment: Are you looking to get the current DateTime of your instances timezone?

Comment: @TSmith: Yes, i want to get the start time of date in my local timezone

Answer (score 1):

In order to get your current instances timezone you would need to be using `System.now()`.

> **[System.now()](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_system.htm)**
> Returns the current date and time in the GMT time zone.
>
> **[Datetime.now()](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_datetime.htm)**
> Returns the current Datetime based on a GMT calendar.

```
DateTime dt = System.now();
System.debug(dt);
// Result will be current DateTime of GMT time zone

Datetime formattedDT = Datetime.newInstance(dt.year(), dt.month(), dt.day(), 0, 0, 0);
System.debug(formattedDT);
// Result will be current DateTime of GMT time zone but formatted to 00:00:00
```

If you feel you wish to know more about how DateTimes and Date compare, take a look at [System vs Date/DateTime class](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/146952/system-vs-date-datetime-class/146958#146958)