# today() in apex

Tags: apex

In process builder, there is date field `Todays_Date__c` value as `today()`. How to write the same in Apex? Here `Todays_Date__c` field data type is `Date`.

Syntax:

```
Account acc = new Account(); 
acc.Name = 'Test';
acc.Todays_Date__c = System.today();
insert acc;
```

Is `System.today()` correct ? Please let me know.

Thanks

Comment: https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/146952/system-vs-date-datetime-class FYI

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `System.today()` or `Date.today()` - both do the same thing and provide today's date in the contextual user's time zone.