# What are the differences between using sObject.sObjectType.getDescribe() and Schema.sObjectType.<sObject>

Tags: apex, pmd

Let's say we have

```
//if(Schema.SObjectType.GroupMember.isCreateable()){
  if(GroupMember.sObjectType.getDescribe().isCreateable()) {
            insert usersToInsert;
        }
```

commented line raises PMD issue during deploing and VS Code always warns about CRUD
where can i read more about it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both have identical behavior, similar to how [`System.now()` and `DateTime.now()` both return the current time in GMT](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/q/146952/2984). Both examples will return the current user's ability to create a GroupMember record. If, indeed, you're getting an error on the first example, file a bug with ApexPMD, as this is definitely a valid way to check CRUD permissions.

As a side note, the Schema isn't ordinarily required, making it an even shorter piece of code that I find more legible:

```
if(sObjectType.GroupMember.isCreateable()){
```